# Making TKinter Loops

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, traceback

I've had problems because I've needed to pause certain functions and what not...  I decided to make a system using the variable `frame` which increments every millisecond, but I'm having trouble pausing again.

This is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk, threading, time

frame = 0

def waitFrames(milliseconds, begin):
    global frame
    if frame < begin+milliseconds:
        waitFrames(3000, begin)

def scrollArrow():
    global frame
    waitFrames(3000, frame)
    print("test")

def update():
    global frame
    frame += 1
    print(frame)
    root.after(100, update)

####-------####
####DIVIDER####
####-------####

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,height=480,width=600)
canvas.pack()

threading.Thread(target=update()).start()
scrollArrow()

root.mainloop()
```

My main issue is the fact that it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SongMaster\v2\times.py", line 31, in <module>
    scrollArrow()
  File "C:\SongMaster\v2\times.py", line 13, in scrollArrow
    waitFrames(3000, frame)
  File "C:\SongMaster\v2\times.py", line 9, in waitFrames
    waitFrames(3000, begin)
```

### Any tips on how to fix this?

As requested by furas, here is the code from my OTHER program, which I'm trying to rewrite:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint
import ImageTk
import winsound, sys, threading, time

combo = 0

def playSong():
    global start
    start = time.clock()

    def func():
        winsound.PlaySound('song2.wav', winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        print("hi")

    threading.Thread(target=func).start()

def deleteImage(imageObject):
    canvas.delete(imageObject)

def scrollToTop(imaget):
    global combo
    if imaget in canvas.find_all() and canvas.coords(imaget)[1] > 0:
        if canvas.coords(imaget)[1] == 80.0:
            print("perfect")
        canvas.move(imaget, 0, -1)
        t.after(2, lambda:scrollToTop(imaget))
    else:
        deleteImage(imaget)

def getClosest(x):
    global combo
    closest = canvas.find_withtag("token")
    distances = [len(closest)]
    for i in range(0,len(closest)):
        coords = canvas.coords(closest[i])
        if coords[0] == x and coords[1] < 120:
            deleteImage(closest[i])
            if coords[1] > 75 and coords[1] < 90:
                combo += 1
                perfect = canvas.create_image(300,300,image=perfectImg)
                t.after(500, lambda:deleteImage(perfect))
            elif coords[1] < 20:
                combo = 0
            else:
                combo = 0
            v.set(combo)
            break


def left(event):
    i = canvas.create_image(210,80,image=bigArrowImg[0])
    t.after(100, lambda:deleteImage(i))
    getClosest(210)

def down(event):
    i = canvas.create_image(270,80,image=bigArrowImg[1])
    t.after(100, lambda:deleteImage(i))
    getClosest(270)

def up(event):
    i = canvas.create_image(330,80,image=bigArrowImg[2])
    t.after(100, lambda:deleteImage(i))
    getClosest(330)

def right(event):
    i = canvas.create_image(390,80,image=bigArrowImg[3])
    t.after(100, lambda:deleteImage(i))
    getClosest(390)

def makeNote(direction):
    t.update()
    global times, start
    start = time.clock()

    times += 1
    arrow = canvas.create_image(pos[direction],480,image=arrowImg[direction],tags="token")
    threading.Thread(target=scrollToTop(arrow)).start()
    #scrollToTop(arrow)

    if(times < 16):
        newDirection = randint(0,3)
        t.after(500, lambda:makeNote(newDirection))



t = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(t,height=480,width=600)
canvas.pack()

bigArrowImg = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/bigLeft.png"),
               ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/bigDown.png"),
               ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/bigUp.png"),
               ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/bigRight.png")]
backgroundImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/background.png")
arrowImg = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/leftArrow.png"),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/downArrow.png"),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/upArrow.png"),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/rightArrow.png")]
perfectImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/PERFECT.png")
pos = [210, 270, 330, 390]

background = canvas.create_image(300,240,image=backgroundImg)
#arrow = canvas.create_image(210,300,image=arrowImg[0],tags="token")
#scrollToTop(arrow)

times = 0

v = StringVar()
Label(t, textvariable=v).pack()
v.set("0")

makeNote(0)
playSong()

t.bind('a', left)
t.bind('d', down)
t.bind('l', up)
t.bind('\'', right)

while 1:
    t.update()
```

The problem with this code is that I can't delay playSong without delaying the arrows...

Answer (score 0):

In `waitFrames` you call `waitFrames` which call `waitFrames` which call `waitFrames` etc. It is called "recursion"- Python has limit to 100 recursions. And computer can do 10 000 (or even more) recursions in second. Don't use recursion in `waitFrames`.

Use `root.after()` to delay action.

```
def scrollArrow():
     root.after(3000, printTest)

def printTest():
     print("test")
```

**EDIT:** answer to new code with `playSound()`

I don't have Windows so I couldn't use winsound so I tested code only with `print("hi")`

```
makeNote(0)

t.after(3000, playSong) # run playSong after 3 seconds

t.bind('a', left)
```

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks again furas but not exactly what I was looking for.

You see, I'm having trouble with root.after() because it seems a little inaccurate at times, but also I'm trying to delay a sound from playing for a second.  Not working :'(

Comment: I think If you use `waitFrames` or `time.sleep()` you delay not only sound but also all functions in program.

Comment: I try `t.after(3000, playSong)` to run `playSound` after 3 seconds - it works. But I couldn't test it with `winsound` - I don't use Windows. But I see "hi" with 3 seconds delay and I can use keyboard before I see "hi".

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more.